# Encryption using libsodium

Tags: encryption, libsodium, nacl-cryptography

I have been struggling to encrypt/decrypt some data using crypto_secretbox_easy() in [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium). I can't seem to find any good documentation on the usage.

I want to get a password from the user, use that to somehow make a key, then encrypt/decrypt the data using that.

The problem with the toy code that I have posted below is that the crypto_secretbox_open_easy() returns -1 from within verify_16.c. Does anyone have any idea where I could find source showing how to use this interface or what could be going wrong? Thanks!

```
 unsigned char * cipher;
 unsigned char * decoded;
 unsigned char * message;
 unsigned long long message_len = 32;
 size_t noncelen = sizeof(char) * crypto_secretbox_noncebytes();
 size_t keylen = sizeof(char) * crypto_secretbox_keybytes();
 unsigned char * nonce = calloc(noncelen, noncelen);
 unsigned char * key = calloc(keylen, keylen);

 message = calloc(32*sizeof(char), sizeof(char) * 32);
 cipher = calloc(32*sizeof(char), sizeof(char) * 32);
 decoded = calloc(32*sizeof(char), sizeof(char) * 32);

 crypto_secretbox_easy((unsigned char *)cipher, (const unsigned char *)message, 
                      message_len, nonce, key);

 crypto_secretbox_open_easy((unsigned char *)decoded, (const unsigned char *) cipher, 
                            message_len, nonce, key);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test/secretbox_easy2.c file` (in the sodium source code) shows how to use it:

```
randombytes_buf(nonce, sizeof nonce);
crypto_secretbox_easy(c, m, mlen, nonce, k);
crypto_secretbox_open_easy(decoded, c, mlen + crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES,
                           nonce, k);
```

In order to derive a key from a password, sodium provides `crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256`.

Answer (score 1):

the size of cipher should be 16 bytes larger then message for the MAC bytes, so alloc 16 more bytes and on open_easy just add + 16 to the message_len.

Also take a look, your call to calloc actually allocate a lot memory than needed, because calloc do the multiplying inside the method.

Comment: Concerning the `calloc` you're right conceptually, but since `sizeof(char) = 1` it actually has no effect in this case.